# Angular 2+ service call illegal return statement

Tags: angular

Getting illegal return statement in exception message; 
however in console window it is throwing numerous errors and warnings 
Error : 
-Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Warning :- Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost/api/AOData/Token

ouput from API end point :-

{"@odata.context":"http://localhost/api/AOData/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"gVynafvIkYcDyR82cGLOTA5zE_iA6cxdf0oxwyEahBrr06eO5k1nUDy2YGyC5_HtpOoV7mWZKqwaN-egahMtJ-mxUDrdkdA0Zbq6HUb1cgQ1:BlCFV_NYcj3SvnfwZJ2Yom0PPowXBBklcNsd0KLYW7whCym19wAT-6fYwiqiH5btrQ4TJxE1istE3CcDMC1kGU3hn3CN_COENwH4I8BOF6M1"}

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Request,RequestMethod, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, ResponseType, ResponseContentType} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/operator/map'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class ApiHelper {
    private serviceUrl =  'http://localhost/api/AOData';  // get the config file;
    antiForgeryToken = '';
    tempData = [];
    userName = 'test@testing.com';
    apiKey = '19DFD5E7-79F5-423F-873E-D4655D1FED3B';
        constructor(private http : Http) {
            this.getToken();
        }

        getToken(){
             var url = this.serviceUrl + "/Token";
             this.get(url).subscribe(data => this.antiForgeryToken = data);
        }

        get(url: string){
                return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Get);
        }

        post(url : string, body : object) {
            return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Post, body)
        }

        put(url : string, body : object) {
            return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Put, body)
        }

        delete(url : string, body : object) {
            return this.request(url, RequestMethod.Delete, body)
        }

        getHeader(){
            var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
            headers['Authorization'] ='Basic ' + btoa(this.userName + ':' + this.apiKey);
            if (this.antiForgeryToken) {
                headers['X-Antiforgery-Token'] = this.antiForgeryToken;
            }
            return headers;
        }

        request(url: string, method: RequestMethod, inputData?: object){
                var header = this.getHeader();
                var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
                    url : url,
                    method : method,
                    headers : header
                    //responseType : ResponseContentType.Json
                });

                if(inputData){
                    requestOptions.body = inputData;
                }

    const request = new Request(requestOptions);

            return this.http.request(request)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((res: Response) => this.onRequestError(res));
                }

        onRequestError(res : Response){
            const statusCode = res.status;
            const body = res.json();
                const error = {
                    statusCode : statusCode,
                    error : body
                }
                return Observable.throw(error)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to make this request from your backend rather than the front end. CORS errors generally can't be handled from the front end,unless you can add it to the 'allowed list' on the server. See this answer:

[CORS issue Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081541/json-rpc-post-request-in-angular-2-4-returns-valid-response-in-chrome-network)

Comment: I have implemented from the server side but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share your server side code?  What happens if you try the request from something like postman?  Does it work?

Comment: installed Microsoft Cors component
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors